# Entity Framework no columns from simple query

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures, edmx

I have the following stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
    @taskName VARCHAR(205) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [dbo].[Table] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   @taskName IS NULL 
            OR @taskName = '' 
            OR Name LIKE '%' + @taskName + '%'
    ORDER BY Name
END
```

Now I created an `File.edmx` generated model, selected the `GetData` stored procedure, when I do a function import and I get "**Get Column Information**", it says

> The selected stored procedure returns no columns

I am `dbo_owner` on the database and it is my user that is in the app.config on generation, and I am even storing the password in `app.config` (temporarily), when I run the procedure from Management Studio, it shows the columns..

**I'm puzzled!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the field names in your select statement rather than just using the *

Comment: Added all the columns instead of *, deleted the Stored Procedure in the Model, re-generated, still same problem, says it returns no columns

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
@taskName VARCHAR(205) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    exec ('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table] WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ' + @taskName + 'IS NULL OR ' + @taskName + ' = \'\' OR Name LIKE \'%' + @taskName + '%\' ORDER BY Name')
END
GO
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't work.. but being puzzled again, I deleted the EDMX and tried again, works now, musta been a fluke

Answer (score 0):

I would try the same process but using only

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[Table] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

instead of the full query. Then you can alter your proc to add the where.

Sometimes EF has problems identifying the return columns due to the were clause